How do I override a Haskell package in nixpkgs via Nix flakes?
This is the flake.nix I'm using
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs?ref=nixos-23.11";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem
      (system:
        let
          pkgs = import nixpkgs {
            inherit system;
            overlays = [
              self.overlays.default
            ];
          };
          hl = pkgs.haskell.lib;
        in
        {
          packages.yesod-subsite-radio-field = pkgs.haskellPackages.yesod-subsite-radio-field;
          packages.default = pkgs.lib.trivial.pipe pkgs.haskellPackages.yesod-subsite-radio-field
            [
              hl.dontHaddock
              hl.enableStaticLibraries
              hl.justStaticExecutables
              hl.disableLibraryProfiling
              hl.disableExecutableProfiling
            ];

          checks = {
            inherit (pkgs.haskellPackages) yesod-subsite-radio-field;
          };

          devShells.default = pkgs.haskellPackages.shellFor {
            packages = p: [ p.yesod-subsite-radio-field ];
            buildInputs = with pkgs.haskellPackages; [
              cabal-fmt
              cabal-install
              hlint
              ghcid
            ];
          };
        }) // {
      overlays.default = _: prev: {
        haskell = prev.haskell // {
          # override for all compilers
          packageOverrides = prev.lib.composeExtensions prev.haskell.packageOverrides (_: hprev: {
            yesod-form =  hprev.callCabal2nix "yesod" ./myyesod/yesod/yesod-form/. { };
            yesod-subsite-radio-field =
              let
                haskellSourceFilter = prev.lib.sourceFilesBySuffices ./. [
                  ".cabal"
                  ".hs"
                ];
              in
              hprev.callCabal2nix "yesod-subsite-radio-field" haskellSourceFilter { };
          });
        };
      };
    };
}

The complete project is here https://github.com/jezen/yesod-subsite-radio-field
I'm trying to override a package (yesod) with a local checkout of the repo.
Essentially similar to this question How do I override a Haskell package in nixpkgs via Nix? but this time via Nix flakes.
I've tried adding (within packageOverrides line 48)
          # override for all compilers
          packageOverrides = prev.lib.composeExtensions prev.haskell.packageOverrides (_: hprev: {
            yesod-form =  hprev.callCabal2nix "yesod" ./myyesod/yesod/yesod-form/. { };
...


However this gives a confusing error of error: getting status of '/nix/store/flards342gmp44m0rscxvn23civ72h96-source/myyesod': No such file or directory even though this path is correct from the local directory. In other words if I run ls ./myyesod/yesod/yesod-form/. I see the expected directory contents.
I've also tried defining the following in my inputs:
    myyesod.url = "git+file:///home/chris/temp/wiptemp/1402/yesod";

And then:
            yesod-form.source =  myyesod;

Or
            yesod-form.source =  hprev.callCabal2nix "yesod" myyesod {};

That doesn't work either.
nix develop
warning: Git tree '/home/chris/temp/wiptemp/1408' is dirty
warning: Git tree '/home/chris/temp/wiptemp/1402/yesod' is dirty
error: getting status of '/nix/store/16kanlk0z2kn4v956fihb42npg0ns6zz-source/flake.nix': No such file or directory
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

Actually if I take a look in /nix/store/16kanlk0z2kn4v956fihb42npg0ns6zz-source/ I see the contents of the repo in question... But it's looking for a flake.nix in there? Does that mean I can't 'use' non flake.nix projects as inputs?
It seems I can fix that with:
    myyesod = {
      url = "git+file:///home/chris/temp/wiptemp/1402/yesod";
      flake = false;
    };

But this in turn gives me an error of:
error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 22 of propagatedBuildInputs for yesod


error: getting status of '/nix/store/flards342gmp44m0rscxvn23civ72h96-source/myyesod': No such file or directory this error occurs in a git controlled directory when the file is not git added. Flakes use git trees to realise file paths and cannot determine them if they are not in the git tree. Try git add -A first and re-try that snippet

Additionally to answer your question about flake inputs, by default inputs are expected to contain a flake.nix, but as you've discovered, setting flake = false removes that expectation and it simply provides you with a store path to the full repository/download of whatever that input was.
